# Adding a button to asp login control

Tags: asp.net

I want to add a button to my login  control but it won't let me. I guess the build in login class works in a different way.

```
<asp:login
        ID="seamenLogin" runat="server"

        TitleText="<strong>Inloggning till sjöläkarwebben. Läkarintyg enligt Manilakonventionen</strong>"
        InstructionText="<br/>Förutsättningar för att använda systemet, ansökan om lösenord<br/>och mer information bl.a.
        om Manila finns på sidan<br/><a href='http:'>http:</a><br/><br/>
        Inloggning med <a class='linkbutton' href='https:/' (BankID, Mobil BankID, ...)</a><br/><br/><br/>
        Inloggning med användarnamn och lösenord kan fortfarande användas men vi<br/>rekommenderar att du övergår till inloggning med e-legitimation redan nu.<br/><br/>" 
        UserNameLabelText="Användarnamn:" 
        PasswordRecoveryText="Har du glömt ditt lösenord?<br/>Här kan du beställa nytt. Det sänds i rekommenderat brev till din folkbokföringsadress." 
        HelpPageUrl="http://www.transportstyrelsen.se/sv/Om-webbplatsen/Inloggning-till-vara-fordonstjanster/E-legitimation/Problem-med-din-e-legitimation/"
        <TitleTextStyle CssClass="heading1" HorizontalAlign="Left"/>
        <LabelStyle CssClass="textboxnamn" HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="100px"/>
        <InstructionTextStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <LoginButtonStyle CssClass="loginbutton"/>
    </asp:login>
```

How do I add a simple button to this code?

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the legacy Login control to a Template instead. 
There should be a small triangle in the right corner which you could click and it should say/go to "**Convert to Template**".

Then you are free to do whatever changed you want to the template. But remember to  be careful not to remove or alter the controls which are already in the table too much from initial state.

Example.
[image]